# Are there risks / pitfalls with using ln -s to link a virtualenv into a local venv within a project directory structure?

Tags: python, unix, virtualenv, ln

I have all my virtual environments in ~/.virtualevs. I am working with a python / flask project that wants to have [PROJECT_HOME]/venv be the virtual environment.

Am I at risk of things breaking and unexpected results if I ln -s ~/.virtualenvs/my_env [PROJECT_HOME]/venv? Or will that just work as expected?

I've set this up and it works. For now. But feels 'klugey'

Answer (score 0):

`ln -s` creates a *soft link* (or *symbolic link*), think of it like a shortcut on Windows, so it's as much safe as you would do operation in the target directory itself.

After creating the symlink, when someone accesses the `[PROJECT_HOME]/venv` link, they will be acessing `~/.virtualenvs/my_env` directory (transparently done by the kernel). So all operations will be happening on the target directory (`~/.virtualenvs/my_env`) as you can imagine.

Also check `man ln` to get more idea on links.

---

But using a symlink would break imports as Python does not check for symlinks then. So unless you've set up `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` correctly to include the symlink directory as well, things would break as far as import machinery is concerned.

But as it's a virtualenv directory, I think it's safe.

Comment: Oh thanks for that. I'm cool with what they are and how they work. I was just worried that if I set my active environment for Python development off the symlinked environment, might I end up with things breaking due to relative links and links out points outside the project directory scope. Does that make sense?